# int and double equality with const in Dart

Tags: dart, int, constants, double, equality

If I do

```dart
final x = (2 == 2.0);
```

Then `x` is `true`.

But if I do

```dart
const x = (2 == 2.0);
```

Then `x` is `false`.

I would expect both to be `true` based on the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-core/num/operator_equals.html):

> If one operand is a double and the other is an int, they are equal if the double has an integer value (finite with no fractional part) and `identical(doubleValue.toInt(), intValue)` is true.

What's going on here?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It should be `true` in both cases. I'll file an issue in the Dart repository.

Comment: @lrn, Thanks. I'm guessing internally it has to do with `doubleValue.toInt()` not being a compile-time constant. However, in that case I would expect the compiler to tell me that I'm not allowed to do `int` and `double` comparisons for `const` values.

Comment: You are [allowed](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/specification/dartLangSpec.tex#L6459) to do `int`/`double` `==` comparisons as a constant expression. The compilers know all about integers and doubles, so it should just work. Here, it doesn't, and that's a bug that should be fixed.